# mahapps : fontfamily not load the font using the style defined nell'app.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

my app.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="MyProject.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>            
            <Style x:Key="Lato-Regular">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Font/#Lato-Regular" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="Lato-Thin">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Font/#Lato-Thin" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="Lato-Semibold">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Font/#Lato-Semibold" />
            </Style>            
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>                
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>             
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

My font in solution "Resources/Font/: Lato-Regular.ttf,Lato-Thin.ttf,Lato-Semibold.ttf

my mainwindows.xaml on textblock:

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MainWindow.xaml"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:metro="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
      xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
      xmlns:p="clr-namespace:MyProject.Properties"
      xmlns:res="clr-namespace:MyProject.Properties;assembly=CDA"
      mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="660" d:DesignWidth="800" Background="#DEDFE4"
      Title="HomePage">

    <Grid>
            <TextBlock  Style="{DynamicResource Lato-Regular}" MouseDown="HomePage_MouseDown" Text="HOMEPAGE" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,22,0,0" Foreground="#fff" FontSize="17" Height="Auto"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</<controls:MetroWindow>
```

My fonts are set by the properties of " always copy " , and they are in solution .
I do not understand why should not go , the software part but the fonts remain standards of the construction of the WPF view .
It can be Mahapps including its fonts , and excludes me those imposed I?

Comment: Have you marked your font as 'Resource' in the Build Action? Have you checked the name of the font? You need to specify the name of the font not the name of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, MahApps defines its own font and used in many controls.
In MahApps' source tree \Style\Fonts.xaml, following are defined:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="DefaultFont">Segoe UI, Lucida Sans Unicode, Verdana</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="HeaderFontFamily">Segoe UI Light, Lucida Sans Unicode, Verdana</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="ContentFontFamily">Segoe UI, Lucida Sans Unicode, Verdana</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="ToggleSwitchFontFamily">Segoe UI Semibold, Segoe UI, Lucida Sans Unicode, Verdana</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="ToggleSwitchHeaderFontFamily">Segoe UI Semibold, Segoe UI, Lucida Sans Unicode, Verdana</FontFamily>
```

Also, search whole MahApps's project for `Segou UI` and should have a few others can be foound.

Personally, i find the easiest way to make MahApp using my font is simply modify its source code and build my own.

Comment: Can you guide me how to modify MahApp's fonts to custom and use that in my Application ? It would be immensely helpful.

Comment: Just change the value in <FontFamily> in \Style\Fonts.xaml